# Web Page Not Using Stylesheet

Tags: html, stylesheet

I have a situation that I was wondering if someone can help me out with.  I have a webpage that displays properly most of the time.  Sometimes however (and this is rare), it does not apply the .css file and just dumps the data out on the screen.  It looks like the .css is not loading.  Is there a way to get the .css to load before the actual html so that this does not happen?  Any ideas on how to best proceed on this?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure the CSS is in the header, and that it is loading - use the Network tab in Chrome

Comment: Hit F12 and open the console, then refresh and see if errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that server is returning 404 on CSS path. Download fiddler or monitor it using Web Developer Tools (Network).

You need to load the CSS in before body actually starts. There might be an issue with your server. It might be returning 404 request while getting CSS from server. You can contact server (hosting) administrator for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check the IIS settings and rights on the server